# Possible to override contacts for just one Nagios host group?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, nagios

The contact for all my linux hosts is the `admins` Nagios `contact_group`. But for this one Linux host would I like that the `contact_group` called `sandradebug` also gets notified.

The problem is, that when I add `contact_groups sandradebug` it is still only `admins` that gets the notification and not also `sandradebug`.

**Question**

How can I include `sandradebug` for this one host, so notifications are also sent there?

**Host template**

```
define host {
  name                          linux-host
  use                           generic-host
  check_command                 check-host-alive
  notification_interval         4320
  notification_options          d,u,r
  contact_groups                admins
  register                      0
}
```

**Host definition**

```
define host {
  use                     linux-host
  host_name               example
  alias                   example
  address                 10.10.10.10
  hostgroups              default-linux-services
  contact_groups          sandradebug
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, we are talking about notifications for the host `example`, aren't we?  Not notifications for the **services** on host `example` (which will be getting data from a completely different template, very likely)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The problem is, that when I add `contact_groups sandradebug` it is
>   still only `admins` that gets the notification and not also
>   `sandradebug`.

Have you restarted the Nagios? Your above configuration will override the template values and only `sandradebug` group will receive these alerts.

> How can I include `sandradebug` for this one host, so notifications
>   are also sent there?

[Object Inheritance](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectinheritance.html) is what you are looking for:

```
define host {
    use                     linux-host
    host_name               example
    alias                   example
    address                 10.10.10.10
    hostgroups              default-linux-services
    contact_groups          +sandradebug
}
```

Using the `+` sign, the host definition uses the data in the template and adds the `sandradebug` to the alerts.

Answer (score 4):

For this, I would just combine the template with the definition since you're only using it once:

```
define host {
  use                     generic-host
  host_name               example
  alias                   example
  address                 10.10.10.10
  hostgroups              default-linux-services
  check_command           check-host-alive
  notification_interval   4320
  notification_options    d,u,r
  contact_groups          sandradebug,admins
}
```

What's likely happening is that your template is overriding the contact group specified.